# Jquery script stops nav from working

Tags: jquery, navigation, nav

At my one page [Website](http://mmd3e12dae42.keaweb.dk/test/index.html) I added a script to make a smooth movement between the different div boxes. But then suddenly the nav stopped working. It is the last one that broke it.

```
<script>
$(function(){
var sections = {},
    _height  = $(window).height(),
    i        = 0;

// Grab positions of our sections 
$('.section').each(function(){
    sections[this.name] = $(this).offset().top;
});

$(document).scroll(function(){
    var pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Look in the sections object and see if any section is viewable on the screen. 
    // If two are viewable, the lower one will be the active one. 
    for(i in sections){
        if(sections[i] > pos && sections[i] < pos + _height){
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $('#nav_' + i).addClass('active');
            }  
        }
    });
});




        $(".scroll").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var full_url = this.href;
            var parts = full_url.split("#");
            var trgt = parts[1];
            var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
            var target_top = target_offset.top;
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);
        }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Says `Object has no method localScroll`, where have you defined the `localScroll()` ?

Comment: Read my down-voted answer, the update I made should fix the problem. Change from `<nav>` to `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console shows error on `line 14`

```
$('#nav').localScroll();
```

Also `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`  error

**UPDATE**

Looks like there is no element by id **section1**

Should be **nav_section1**

This line

```
$("#"+trgt).offset();
```

supposed to be

```
$("#nav_"+trgt).offset();  OR  $('[href="#' + trgt + "]').offset()
```

Also make sure the element is **not hidden** when you get the `offset()` values..

Comment: I get an syntax error from the last bit after OR. When I tried to remove that part the syntax error disappeared. I could also use the navigation again, but it didnt go to the different divs, it just scrolled about 500 px down.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle replicating the isuue so that it can be worked on

Answer (score -1):

Gotta love Chrome's Inspector...You missed a semicolon.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#nav').localScroll();
});
</script>
```

---

Why are you using `<nav>`? The instructions talks about using a `<div>`

---

Try this out:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="nav_section1" href="#section1" class="scroll active">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_section2" href="#section2" class="scroll">&gt;Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_section3" href="#section3" class="scroll">&gt;Section 3</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_section4" href="#section4" class="scroll">&gt;Section 4</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_section5" href="#section5" class="scroll">&gt;Section 5</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_section6" href="#section6" class="scroll">&gt;Section 6</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_section7" href="#section7" class="scroll">&gt;Section 7</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```